# What is $|1⟩_|0⟩_=|0⟩_|1⟩_$ called? Is it possible in quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-state

I have read about the no-cloning theorem and read that if the states are known then it is a different situation, I was wondering about this transportation of qubits, can the $U$ be for example an $X$-gate then we say this is possible?
$$|1⟩_|0⟩_=|0⟩_|1⟩_$$

Comment: Yes, it is called the SWAP gate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Swap_gate

Answer (score 3):

The operation $|\psi⟩_|\phi⟩_=|\phi⟩_|\psi⟩_$ (swapping the state of the two qubits) is a unitary operation. So, it is a valid quantum operation. It is known in quantum computing as the $\text{SWAP}$-gate and  is represented by the matrix
$$\text{SWAP} = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

On the other hand, cloning means to create an independent and identical copy of an *arbitrary unknown* quantum state. That is:

$$|\psi⟩_|0⟩_=|\psi⟩_|\psi⟩_$$

No-cloning theorem states that such unitary operator $U$ does not exist.

Comment: Just to be clear, the unitary $U$ as specified by the OP is not uniquely defined. SWAP is one possible option. Even easier (from some perspective) would be $X\otimes X$

Comment: Indeed. But since he mentioned this as an example, I just focused on what he called "transportation of qubits". I updated my answer for more clarity